# Can I use Jersey in my commercial application?

Tags: jersey

As the title, I would like to ask you all "Can I use Jersey in my commercial application?".

I have read [Jersey license](https://jersey.java.net/license.html), but I'm confused.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Glassfish libraries in proprietary software](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646431/using-glassfish-libraries-in-proprietary-software)

Comment: Jersey is the same CDDL + GPLv2 combination as Glassfish, which already has an answer.